# How can I compare values in 2D array with values in 1D array in GoLang?

Tags: arrays, go, int32, absolute-value, type-2-dimension

I need to compare 1D array's and 2D array's values and to return the result array which has similar values using Go:

```
func absolutePermutation(n int32, k int32) []int32 {
    var position []int32

    var i, j int32
    var result []int32
    for i = 1; i <= n; i++ {
        position[i-1] = i
    }

    x := getPermutations(position)
    resVal := permNum(n)
    fmt.Println(x)

    for i = 0; i < resVal; i++ {

        for j = 0; j < 4; j++ {

            fmt.Println(x[i][j])

            **if int32(math.Abs(float64(position[(j*resVal)+i])-float64(x[i][j]))) == k** {
                result[i] = x[i][j]
            } else {
                continue
            }
        }
    }

    return result
}

func getPermutations(elements []int32) [][]int32 {
    permutations := [][]int32{}
    if len(elements) == 1 {
        permutations = [][]int32{elements}
        return permutations
    }
    for i := range elements {
        el := make([]int32, len(elements))
        copy(el, elements)

        for _, perm := range getPermutations(append(el[0:i], el[i+1:]...)) {
            permutations = append(permutations, append([]int32{elements[i]}, perm...))
        }
    }
    return permutations
}


func permNum (n int32) int32 {

    if n == 0 {
        return 1
    } 
    
    return n * permNum(n-1)
}
```

I tried to create position (1D array into 2D array here.) but it didn't make sense.
As a newbie to GoLang, I get this error in this code which is written to get the permutation of a given number:

> runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0

Answer (score 0):

I solved to some extent. you can refer to this.

```
 func absolutePermutation(n int32, k int32) []int32 {
        var buffer [1024 * 1024]int32
        position := buffer[0:n]
        result := make([]int32, n)    
        var i, j int32
    
    for i = 1; i <= n; i++ {
        position[i-1] = i
    }
    x := getPermutations(position)

    for i = 0; i < permNum(n); i++ {
        for j = 0; j < n; j++ {  
            if int32(math.Abs(float64(position[j])-float64(x[i][j]))) == k {
                result[j] = x[i][j]
                if j==n-1{
                    return result
                }       
            }else{
            break
            }
        }
    }
    result = nil
    return result    
}
```